# Trying to get a Sum of Distinct values. Get the error "Sum function only accepts a column reference as an argument"

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data that looks like this:
This is what my data looks like to clarify:

```
nums | category | name | date

1000, foo, a, 6/15
1000, foo, b, 6/15
1000, foo, c, 6/15
500, bar, g, 6/15
2000, foo, a, 6/14
2000, foo, b, 6/14
```

Nums is just the sum of a different value by category. When the same category shows up multiple times for a date, it will have the same Nums value.

I just want to get the total of Nums for my date range. I can't just sum them because values are duplicated because of the multiple entries of the same category. I just want a sum of the distinct (in my actual data, it's very unlikely there will be a duplicate)

`Measure = SUM(DISTINCT(MyData[nums]))`

I get "The SUM function only accepts a column reference as an argument". The DISTINCT function should be returning a column though, right? I tried the same thing with VALUES, but got the same error. How am I supposed to get the sum of distinct values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need an iterator like `SUMX`:

```
Measure = SUMX ( DISTINCT ( MyData[nums] ),  [nums] )
```

This iterates through the table in the first argument, `DISTINCT(MyData[nums])`, and for each row in that table totals up the value given by the expression in the second argument, `[nums]`.

Comment: Thank you so much!